# File details: size, last modified time, md5 value, path\filename

Tags: php, windows, powershell, hash, md5

*Media archiving. Windows. PowerShell. (or by php in command line?)*

Any way I can include the **md5 hash value** for each file? This script provides file size, last modified time, path\filename; having an md5 value would be useful. (Capability to handle entire disks, 100K+ files/many TBs, 4K video [large] files, etc. with ease (i.e., a clean and robust function].)

The results needs to be written into a .txt file and placed into the current working dir.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File filelist.txt
```

Comment: Please don't post requirements (your "Should be able to..." portion) as though you're expecting the work to be done for you, just post what you're attempting to do and where you're getting stuck so people can get you un-stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell v5 (maybe 4?), you can use [`get-filehash`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Get-FileHash) to compute the hash of each file. Then use that in a computed property in `select-object`.

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object length,lastwritetime,fullname,@{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}}
```

Comment: `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` Major 5, Minor 1. i tried the above suggestion as is, but does not provide md5, only displays length, LWT, Fullname. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: as a control, i tried this `Get-FileHash $pshome\powershell.exe | Format-List` and i got the expected results as shown in [Get-FileHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Get-FileHash). so what i am doing wrong with your script?

Comment: `get-filehash C:\test.txt -Algorithm SHA384 | Format-List` this is working, as well. so where is the problem?

Comment: thanks!!! i included the 'Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize' and changed the order of the columns, and now it is perfect (long paths blocked out the [last] md5 column, i assume).

Comment: Don't use `Format-*` until you're ready for final, human-readable output. In the case of your script here, I'd recommend against using it at all and instead output to a CSV file with `export-csv -notypeinformation` so that the data is *usable* beyond your script.

Comment: thanks! i eliminated `Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File  md5_filelist.txt` and replaced it with `export-csv md5_filelist.csv -notypeinformation`

Answer (score 0):

A small Python script is more flexible and allows non-windows users as well to execute it:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import hashlib


def md5hash(file):
    with open(file, "rb") as fp:
        data = fp.read()
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()


for path in sorted(Path(".").glob("*")):
    size = path.stat().st_size / 10**6
    last_modified = path.stat().st_mtime()
    hash_value = md5hash(path)
    print(f"{size:.1f}MB,{last_modified},{hash_value},{path}")
```

Comment: getting the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\testcode\md5_test-1.py", line 15, in <module>
    last_modified = path.stat().st_mtime()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: Try path.stat().st_mtime, hence no ()

Comment: `last_modified = path.stat().st_mtime` works nice! Instead of displaying on the screen, how can I export it to a filelist.txt file in the current working directory?